# Exists() not working with second variable Cloud Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my project, I want to control access to a document by checking if the user's uid is part of a subcollection (that holds all of the members of that document) of that document.
When I want to check this with the exists() method, it does not grant permission when it's supposed to.

```
 match /events/{season}/events/{code} {
    function isVV (season, code) {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/events/$(season)/events/$(code)/vv/$(request.auth.uid));
    }

    allow read: if isVV(season, code);
```

When I replace the $(code) with the value I'm currently testing, the rule passes and everything works as expected. When I'm using a variable it does not.

Any Cloud Firestore Rules experts that can help me out?
Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Does it work if you change the names of the function parameters? For example, `function isVV (userseason, usercode)`. Maybe the parameter names are clashing with the variables set by the `match` statement.

Comment: unfortunately not. By entering a static value for code, I confirmed that the season variable is working. I tried it again for good measure but no cigar. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Same result if you call `exists()` directly from the rule? -- `allow read: if exists(...);`

Comment: Yes, same result :/

Comment: any luck with this????

Comment: getting the same problem with `get`

Comment: might be related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107132/firestore-query-in-app-gives-permission-denied-while-simulator-works-fine/51123361#51123361)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason exists does not like to evaluate variables other than database in the Firestore rules. Looking at the documentation I was able to find that the exists function actually takes in a `Path`, described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Path

Using this information I was able to achieve something similar to what you want above by first constructing the path as a string using concatenation and then passing this to the `exists` function.

For your example above this would look like:

```
match /events/{season}/events/{code} {
  function isVV (database, season, code) {
    return exists(path("/databases/" + database + "/documents/events/" + season + "/events/" + code + "/vv/" + request.auth.uid));
  }

  allow read: if isVV(database, season, code);
}
```

Note: you have to pass the database as a function param as I found that when using string concatenation in this fashion, it is not auto populated like it is when using something like `exists(/databases/$(database))`